# Manage Retention (Information Management Policy) on library template is not working

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-library

I have library for which I have enabled "Information Management Policy" from Library settings. I have added retention stage on Expiration Date (Site Column in library). It is working very fine.

But when I create template of same Library and create new library with that template. Then if I check for "Information Management Policy" and retention stage, I do not find anything.

It seems that creating template of library does not retaining "Information Management Policy" with it.

Is it the behavior of SharePoint? Or do I need to do something else to retain it in the template.

Please give your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Create an information management policy for a list or library If your organization needs to apply a specific information management policy to a very limited set of content, you can create an information management policy that **applies only to an individual list or library**. This method of creating an information management policy is the **least flexible**, because **the policy applies only to one location, and it cannot be exported or reused for other locations**. However, sometimes you may need to create unique information management policies with limited applicability to address specific situations.

Information management policies link on settings page for document library

[Notes](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Introduction-to-information-management-policies-63a0b501-ba59-44b7-a35c-999f3be057b2)

You can create an information management policy for a list or library only if that list or library does not support multiple content types. If a list or library supports multiple content types, you need to define an information management policy for each individual list content type that is associated with that list or library. (Instances of a site content type that are associated with a specific list or library are known as list content types.)

To control which policies are used in a site collection, site collection administrators can disable the ability to set policy features directly on a list or library. When this restriction is in effect, users who manage lists or libraries are limited to selecting policies from the site collection Policies list.

Comment: Thanks Varun but "Library and Folders" is the data source for my "Information Management Policy" not content type. And creating template from library setting does not shows the effect of "IMP"